# Android MPChart: drawing lines of different plots on the same activity in different colors

Tags: java, android, plot, mpandroidchart, real-time-updates

I'm using the MPAndroidChart library to create several plots and update them in realtime with different sources of data. I want each plot to have a line of a different color. The problem is that all plots show up with a line of the same color even if I specify another color for a different plot. Moreover I need to update each chart with different sources of data but I suspect all of them are using just one source of data which suggests to me that the same problem with the color is happening with the data.

This is part of how I specify the different plots inside my activity file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/chart1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/chart2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    ...
```

I have 8 of these plots stacked together and they show correctly on my app one after the other. Then on my activity file I initialize each one of them like this

```
OnChartValueSelectedListener ol = new OnChartValueSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry entry, Highlight h) {
            //entry.getData() returns null here
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    };

mChart1 = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
mChart1.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(ol);

mChart2 = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart2);
mChart2.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(ol);
...
```

Then when I'm receiving the data I do

```
    LineData data1 = mChart1.getData();

    if (data1 != null) {

        ILineDataSet set1 = data1.getDataSetByIndex(0);

        // set.addEntry(...); // can be called as well

        if (set1 == null) {
            set1 = createSet();
            data1.addDataSet(set1);
        }

        data1.addEntry(new Entry(set1.getEntryCount(), f), 0);
        data1.notifyDataChanged();

        // let the chart know it's data has changed
        mChart1.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // limit the number of visible entries
        mChart1.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20);

        // move to the latest entry
        mChart1.moveViewToX(data1.getEntryCount());

    }

    LineData data2 = mChart2.getData();


    if (data2 != null) {

        ILineDataSet set2 = data2.getDataSetByIndex(0);

        // set.addEntry(...); // can be called as well

        if (set2 == null) {
            set2 = createSet2();
            data2.addDataSet(set2);
        }

        data2.addEntry(new Entry(set2.getEntryCount(), f), 0);
        data2.notifyDataChanged();

        // let the chart know it's data has changed
        mChart2.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // limit the number of visible entries
        mChart2.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20);

        // move to the latest entry
        mChart2.moveViewToX(data2.getEntryCount());

    }
```

And then I have the createSet functions which assign a different color

```
private LineDataSet createSet() {

    LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(null, "");
    set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    set1.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set1.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
    set1.setLineWidth(1f);
    set1.setCircleRadius(1f);
    set1.setFillAlpha(65);
    set1.setFillColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
    set1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    set1.setValueTextSize(0.1f);
    set1.setDrawValues(false);
    return set1;
}

private LineDataSet createSet2() {

    LineDataSet set2 = new LineDataSet(null, "");
    set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    set2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    set2.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
    set2.setLineWidth(1f);
    set2.setCircleRadius(1f);
    set2.setFillAlpha(65);
    set2.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(44, 117, 117));
    set2.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    set2.setValueTextSize(0.1f);
    set2.setDrawValues(false);
    return set2;
}
```

Where you see the set color is one set to getHoloBlue() which is a default test color and the other is set to Color.GREEN. The problem is all 8 of the plots have the getHoloBlue color. If I put another color on the first createSet function they all change to that color.

I'm new to Android development so I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
ILineDataSet set1 = data1.getDataSetByIndex(0);
ILineDataSet set2 = data2.getDataSetByIndex(0);
```

Create separate datasets for every chartview as:

```
LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(lineEntries1, "legend");
LineDataSet lineDataSet2 = new LineDataSet(lineEntries2, "legend");
// line entries are arraylist of strings
enter code here
```

After that:

```
LineData lineData1 = new LineData(lineDataSet1);
LineData lineData2 = new LineData(lineDataSet2);
```

Then:

```
mChart1.setData(lineData1);
mChart2.setData(lineData2);
```

Follow that flow I think there is issue you are making array of dataset which is not required moreover I think you are doing something wrong in defining datasets and data. In normal flow we provide dataset to data but in your solution its opposite.

For normal flow of single line in single chart view follow example below and add different chartviews and datasets in that way.

Example:

```
    ArrayList<Entry> lineEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(0, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(1, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(2, 3));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(3, 4));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(4, 2));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(5, 3));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(6, 1));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(7, 5));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(8, 7));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(9, 6));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(10, 4));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(11, 5));

    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineEntries, "Oil Price");
    lineDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    lineDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    lineDataSet.setLineWidth(2);
    lineDataSet.setColor(getColor("defaultBlue"));
    lineDataSet.setCircleColor(getColor("defaultOrange"));
    lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(6);
    lineDataSet.setCircleHoleRadius(3);
    lineDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true);
    lineDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextColor(getColor("primaryDark"));

    LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);

    lineChart.getDescription().setText("Price in last 12 days");
    lineChart.getDescription().setTextSize(12);
    lineChart.setDrawMarkers(true);
    lineChart.setMarker(markerView(context));
    lineChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(lowerLimitLine(2,"Lower Limit",2,12,getColor("defaultOrange"),getColor("defaultOrange")));
    lineChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(upperLimitLine(5,"Upper Limit",2,12,getColor("defaultGreen"),getColor("defaultGreen")));
    lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
    lineChart.animateY(1000);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1.0f);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(lineDataSet.getEntryCount());
    lineChart.setData(lineData);
```

Comment: By doing this you get both lines in same chart view. For further assistance do let me know mate. Happy coding !

Comment: Thanks! But this will show one chart with two lines right? What I want is two (and more) charts each with their own line. I now have 8 charts but the lines on each one are the same although the data source from all are different..

Comment: Oh i get it. Look at the edited answer. Hope this will work mate. Best of luck :)

Comment: Hey, didn't work either but thanks for trying to help anyways :) It isn't a problem that I have all my linear layouts for each chart in the same relative layout right?

Comment: no buddy I dont think so that to have them in same relative layout is a problem.

Comment: Sorry buddy i have to go out for dinner i will get back to u soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166477/discussion-between-atirag-and-m-saad-lakhan).

Comment: Buddy I edited answer and added an example please follow that example. Thats working example I implemented.